# How to significantly reduce size of dataset (say .csv) to analyse in Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

Suppose we have 1GB dataset(say .csv) to analyse and we are unable to run quickly as delay is too much to run again and again, what to do in order to make data scalable enough to analyse.

Comment: "say .csv" so is it a .CSV or is it something else? What kind of data is it? How long is to long? What are your hardware constraints? Are you doing this over a network? We need more in than "I have a lot of data and it's going slow."\

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Many times I faced this problem and got a simple solution by making Data Frames of the dataset and creating new dataset (say .csv) by making an output out of Data Frames and what's most significant is creation of new Data sets almost 1/8 th of the real size of datasets. Below is an example of how it can work.

```
import pandas as pd
df=pd.DataFrame()
df=pd.read_csv('a1.csv')
```

Now after minor operations on data(if required), you can output data and get significantly small .csv file to analyse data.

```
df.to_csv('a2.csv')
```

Please correct me in case you have some other method to work on larger datasets using Pandas.

Answer (score 3):

Another solution is to use the `nrows` kwarg in `read_csv`, e.g.:

```
df = pd.read_csv('a1.csv', nrows=100)
```

This would read in just the first 100 rows.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this would solve your problem.
If you reduce the actual size of your data by getting a representative random sample, you can perform tests and fit models just to run some analysis and check the state of your data.

You can create a **random** sample of the data based on percentage, using the `pd.sample()` function:

```py
df = pd.read_csv('mydata.csv')
sampled_df = df.sample(frac=0.3) # Get 30% of the data
len(sampled_df)                  # check length
```

Or, you can create a sliced sample with specific number of lines

```py
df = pd.read_csv('mydata.csv')
Specific_Rows = df.sample(n=40) # Select 40 random rows of your dataset
print(Specific_Rows)
```